# Socket validation using Poco c++ libraries

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, poco

I'm working on an application that needs to perform network communication and decided to use the [poco c++ libraries](http://pocoproject.org/). After going through the [network tutorial](http://pocoproject.org/slides/200-Network.pdf) I can't seem to find any forms of validation on establishing a network connection.

In the following example a client tries to connect to a server using a tcp socket stream:

```
#include "Poco/Net/SocketAddress.h"
#include "Poco/Net/StreamSocket.h"
#include "Poco/Net/SocketStream.h"
#include "Poco/StreamCopier.h"
#include <iostream>  

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 Poco::Net::SocketAddress sa("www.appinf.com", 80);
 Poco::Net::StreamSocket socket(sa);
 Poco::Net::SocketStream str(socket);
 str << "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        "Host: www.appinf.com\r\n"
        "\r\n";
 str.flush();
 Poco::StreamCopier::copyStream(str, std::cout);
 return 0;
}
```

However, I couldn't find any information related to:

- Error checking(what if www.appinf.com is unavailable or doesn't exist for that matter)
- The type of exception these calls may raise

The only mention is that a [SocketStream](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/Poco.Net.SocketStream.html) may hang if the receive timeout is not set for the socket when using formated inputs.

How can I check if a host is alive and may set up a tcp connection, implement a method such as:

```
void TCPClient::connectTo(std::string host, bool& connected, unsigned int port) {
     std::string hi = "hi";
     Poco::Net::SocketAddress clientSocketAddress(host, port);
     Poco::Net::StreamSocket clientStreamSocket;
     // try to connect and avoid hang by setting a timeout
     clientStreamSocket.connect(clientSocketAddress, timeout); 
     // check if the connection has failed or not,
     // set the connected parameter accordingly
     // additionally try to send bytes over this connection
     Poco::Net::SocketStream clientSocketStream(clientStreamSocket);
     clientSocketStream << hi << std::endl;
     clientSocketStream.flush();
     // close the socket stream
     clientSocketStream.close();
     // close stream
     clientStreamSocket.shutdown();
}
```